# Need to fetch Values from Date table related with User Table

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I have 2 Tables, One user table and other Date Table.

Date contains all the leaves applied by a user with foreign key user id.

PFB model code:

```
class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    email=db.Column(db.String(120),unique=True,nullable=False)
    profile_pic=db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False,default="defaultdp.jpg")
    password=db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)

    datatime=db.relationship('Date',backref='date',lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.username}"
class Date(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    date_comp=db.Column(db.String(120),nullable=False)
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'),nullable=False)
```

I have created a route, to have a form which is a selection of user, based on which i can query and get the leave dates for that user.

```
class Appliedcomps(FlaskForm):
    usernames=QuerySelectField(
        'Associate Username',
        query_factory=lambda: models.User.query,
        get_label='id'
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

```
@app.route('/appliedcomps', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def appliedcomps():
    form = Appliedcomps()
    uid=form.usernames.data
    if form.validate_on_submit:

        d=Date.query.filter_by(user_id=uid).all()

    return render_template('appliedcomps.html', form=form,d=d)
```

```
{% extends "layout.html"%}
{%block contents%}
<form method="GET" action="">
{{ form.usernames(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}

{{form.submit(class_="btn")}}

</form>
{%for u in d%}
    {{d.date_comp}}
{%endfor%}


{%endblock contents%}
```

This query does not work, I'm not getting any dates display. Please guide me on how to fetch values from 2 tables related thro sqlalchemy in flask application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is simple, you're not giving you items a html element in the template and you're calling the whole object `d` instead of the iterated items `u`,

change the template to the following . I have added an unodered list element for the items.

```
{% extends "layout.html"%}

{%block contents%}

<form method="GET" action="">
{{ form.usernames(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}

{{form.submit(class_="btn")}}

</form>
<ul>
{%for u in d%}
    <li>{{u.date_comp}}</li>
{%endfor%}
</ul>

{%endblock contents%}
```

Also change your GET params getter from `uid = form.usernames.data` to `uid = request.args.get('usernames')`, make sure you also import `from flask import request` at the imports section.